# Many entities in single table and repository pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my database I store a media, eg. movies, series (seasons, episodes), music (groups, albums, tracks).
All this data is stored in single table (Media). 
Question: how should I work with this table in my code? I have two options:

1. Create single repository and one large model for all media types.
2. Create model and repository for each media type.

Which is better and why?

Comment: Are you able to go a step backwards and think about why you put all this different types into one table? It probably would be a way better design to have a seperate table for each media type.

Comment: Second one. Why? Well, there is no one reason; all reasons that go for OOP.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a model and repo for each media type. I think it would be better than a robust one, because at this point you can't be sure wether you will need to do any type specific preformatting or validation or anything. It might be a little overhead for now, but it will be much more maintainable and less complex in the future. Its hands off the better solution.

Btw. i think this is why classes and inheritance was invented in the first place :) You use object oriented language so you might aswell take advantage of it...

Answer (score 0):

You can define an abstract base Model class for the Media and derive all concrete Media model from that.

Now you can have a Media repository handling all kinds of media. Which media you retrieve you can resolve by the class type you get.

```
interface IMediaRepository
{
    ICollection<Media> GetAll();
    ICollection<T> GetAllByType<T>() where T : Media;
}
```

The repository itself wraps the database query and it does not matter for the repository if you have one table for all or separate table for each media kind.